# JDBC_PING on infinispan server not working

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, cluster-computing, infinispan

I'm in phase of experimentation with infinispan server and I have a problem in set-up a infinispan cluster on my local machine.
Configuration files:
I change configuration file cluster.xml by changing part of jgroup stack with udp stack and jdbc_ping discovery.

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:infinispan:server:jgroups:7.0" default-stack="${jboss.default.jgroups.stack:udp-jdbc}">
        <stack name="udp-jdbc">
            <transport type="UDP" socket-binding="jgroups-udp">
                <property name="ip_mcast">false</property>
    </transport>
            <protocol type="JDBC_PING">
                <property name="connection_url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/jgroups</property>
                <property name="connection_username">root</property>
                <property name="connection_password">root</property>            
                <property name="connection_driver">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    </protocol>                
            <protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-udp-fd"/>
            <protocol type="FD_ALL"/>
            <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
            <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2"/>
            <protocol type="UNICAST3"/>
            <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
            <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
            <protocol type="UFC"/>
            <protocol type="MFC"/>
            <protocol type="FRAG2"/>
            <protocol type="RSVP"/>
        </stack>
```

I put mysql driver in folder standalone/deployments, run the server and here is what I have as output

```
20:13:15,389 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar" (runtime-name: "mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar")
20:13:15,461 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.jgroups.channel.clustered: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.jgroups.channel.clustered: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JDBC Driver required for JDBC_PING protocol could not be loaded: 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups.subsystem.ChannelService.start(ChannelService.java:74)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JDBC Driver required for JDBC_PING protocol could not be loaded: 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
    at org.jgroups.protocols.JDBC_PING.loadDriver(JDBC_PING.java:267)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.JDBC_PING.init(JDBC_PING.java:93)
    at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.initProtocolStack(ProtocolStack.java:860)
    at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.setup(ProtocolStack.java:481)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.init(JChannel.java:848)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.<init>(JChannel.java:159)
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups.JChannelFactory.createChannel(JChannelFactory.java:87)
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups.subsystem.ChannelService.start(ChannelService.java:69)
    ... 5 more

20:13:15,559 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
20:13:15,561 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver (version 5.1)
20:13:15,563 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
20:13:15,564 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar_com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver_5_1
20:13:15,597 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 18) JBAS018559: Deployed "mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar" (runtime-name : "mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar")
20:13:15,599 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.jgroups.channel.clustered: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.jgroups.channel.clustered: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JDBC Driver required for JDBC_PING protocol could not be loaded: 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
```

As you can see from the jboss log, the subsystem infinispan:server:jgroups failed to start because the JDBC driver isn't loaded (required by JDBC_PING), but after that step infinispan server successfully deployed mysql jdbc driver. This same error occupy in conditions where I work with datasource.
Is there any way to tell the infinispan:server:jgroups subsystem to be started before driver loading or before jndi naming creation ?
Or any workaround that will help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try install a JDBC Driver as a Core Module, https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Install_a_JDBC_Driver_as_a_Core_Module1.html

Comment: I try that solution (create reference with datasource), but it doesn't work. As far I can tell from the log file the problem is that these two processes of creation are run in parallel by two separate threads, so if I'm lucky it will create cluster :)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but maybe intalling as a global module. See http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/how-to-install-a-module-on-jboss-as-7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For direct JDBC use, you need to allow JGroups module to load your JDBC driver module. To do that, install JDBC driver jar as a module, then open `modules/system/layers/base/org/jgroups/main/module.xml`, add your JDBC driver module under the dependencies section.

For datasource lookup with EAGER caches, I think it's currently not possible to ensure that the datasource is available before JGroups tries to use it. The services boot order is controlled by programmatic dependencies but there is no way to declare the dependencies through config files so JGroups doesn't wait for the datasource.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but it doesn't work. I think that module thing is jboss/wildfly is more like maven repository and creating compile time dependencies, than it is for runtime dependencies.

Comment: I'm not sure your config is correct but it's working on my side using Infinispan Server 7.0.2.Final.

Comment: The server config file alone is not enough to validate, please include:

1. MySQL driver jar location
2. MySQL driver module.xml
3. JGroups module.xml
4. Full server.log

Comment: MySql driver jar location: standalone/deployments ,
jGroups xml: http://pastebin.com/y0BH0haD ,
Server.log : http://pastebin.com/0Th4eNng

Comment: I don't see JDBC driver module in your JGroups module.xml. Please re-read my answer.

Comment: The previous configuration was with deployment of the driver in standalone/deployments, but here is the second configuration with datasource configuration
jgroups-module.xml http://pastebin.com/pFh6iZFL
mysql-module.xml http://pastebin.com/fjTkgVue
configuration: http://pastebin.com/8qs0xdMA
server.log: http://pastebin.com/Dtjp68bv

Comment: Please take a deep breath. I'm saying DataSource is not possible and you're trying DataSource.

Comment: Thanks, for the flashlight, it finally worked. As you told me, I put mysql module reference in jgroups module, and in the configuration I use the driver class. Thanks again